# Solution of RBF constraint least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution, regression, least-squares

I have to design a matrix A that solves a linear system:

$=$, where x is a known complex vector and y is a known complex vector.

The requirement is that A is an RBF kernel, i.e., it has the following structure:

$a_{ij} = \alpha \, \exp\left (\frac{-d_{ij}^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$, where d is the distance between each element in the matrix.

I need to find at least one example of A.  $\sigma $ and $\alpha$ can be whatever.

Any ideias?

Luisa.